# PowerShell and Command Prompt returning Unknown Option error for --exclude and --include (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to search for a string of characters in AWS CLI, but exclude a specific file type to narrow down the results to the file type I'm looking for, but no matter the iteration I try, both PowerShell and Command prompt give me the same error message.

aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'searchtext')]" --exclude "*" --include "*.pdf"

Edit: running aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'searchtext')]" works just fine

Comment: I don't have this command.  Is it really a .cmd script?  Often the doublequotes are lost between powershell and external commands.

Comment: The command doesn't support those options. S3 in general doesn't support server-side filtering outside of prefix and delimiter. You need to do your searching/filtering on the client side.

Comment: These commands are in the instructions from Amazon specifically for the CLI though. And searching without the exclude/include works just fine.